# Clear contents of cells either side of a search value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search an entire worksheet (or active used area), find a cell with a specified value, and clear the contents of that cell and the cells on either side of it.

I have a space delimited imported text file. At the end of each entry in the report there is a tag line that I don't want in the end product.

The cell that I am searching for can be in any column due to the nature of the text document I imported (which I have no control over).

I have been going through these forums for a while now and I can't find an answer.

Example would be in a sentence with each word being in a different cell (and not necessarily on the same row):

> John likes to walk with his dog.

I would like to search for the word "his" and clear the contents of the cells either side so that the sentence would now read:

> John likes to walk

Comment: Surely you can find an example here that shows you how to search, right? You need to break this down into two steps: 1) doing the search, and 2) clearing the cells on either side of the found location. So start with finding out how to do the search. In fact, I found an [example of doing so](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10437858/62576) that also contains the answer to the rest of your problem, and it took 30 seconds of looking at the results of a search for `[excel-vba] find text` here.

Comment: As @KenWhite was getting at, SO isn't a code writing platform. If you could post some of the code you've tried, show where you're having issues or what parts you don't understand, we'd be more than happy to guide you in the right direction. If you need help on asking a good question, [refer to here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub Scan_For_Footer()
Dim rngTotal As Range, cl As Range
Const FooterText = "text to look for"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Set rngTotal = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
rngTotal.Select ' this is just to show the region that is selected.  Once you're happy, delete it
For Each cl In rngTotal
    If cl.Text = FooterText Then
        cl.Offset(0, -1).Clear
        cl.Clear
        cl.Offset(0, 1).Clear
    End If
Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. I will try this when code when I get a chance to later today.

Comment: How is this answer not useful if it works exactly as the OP wishes?